# Program to visualize geodesics and linear projection of an ellipsoid simultaneously

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry, projections, curve

I am trying to solve a problem in computer graphics but to do it I need to be able to see a comparison of geodesic lines and straigth line projections on the ellipsoid.

I have not been able to figure out how to fing the mathematical definition of geodesics (linear projections are easy).

I was wondering if anybody has coded somehting like this already or is aware ofa  tool I could use?